# you can feel or you might feel?

Tags: modal-verbs

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> You can feel that it is impossible for resistance be strictly equal to
>   zero, because may be it follows us to some contradiction with Ohm's law.

Which would be idiomatic here, "can feel" or "might feel"? What is the difference?

Comment: Is this your original sentence, or is it excerpted from something? I see a couple other issues that might affect the can vs. might question.

Comment: It is from a question posted here which was a request for "proofreading" and so was doomed to be closed. I am creating a series of questions based on it, in the hope that the answers will be helpful to that person while also being helpful to the visitors at large. There is another question about "follows us"

Comment: Good Guy TRomano! ... But I still can't decipher the second half of that sentence.

Comment: The **to** before **be** is missing. There should be a **to**, or else it will be an incorrect sentence. Not only that I can't understand the part after "because...". It seems like there is also mistake :)

Comment: Substitute "leads us to " for "follows us to" and it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "may" or "might" in this context. It's a common English rhetorical device for the first clause of a sentence to concede a point, and for the second clause to rebut it, and that construction often takes the form "**You might** think *X*, **but** actually *Y*." In other words, the first clause of the sentence sets up a potential counter-argument and the second clause explains why it's not valid.

It's also acceptable to break the construction into two sentences, with something like, "**You might** think *X*, because of *A,B,* and *C*. Actually, the truth is *Y*". Obviously, you can replace the second sentence with whatever other rebuttal you'd like.

The reason that the word "might" is appropriate here is because "might" expresses uncertainty. Here, "might" acknowledges the possibility that your opponent thinks *X* and, regardless, sets you up to counter it. If you were to use the word "can", you would sound as though you were giving your opponent permission to think *X* or stating that your opponent had the ability to think *X*, neither of which makes sense here.

There's another construction, though, that does use "can". It's primarily found in speech, but the construction, "You can do *X*, but *Y*" has a different meaning altogether. In that construction, you concede that your opponent is able to do something, but then go on to explain why it's a bad idea. For example, "You can eat that cookie, but you'll spoil your dinner." This construction, thought, isn't appropriate here because you're countering an idea, not rejecting a course of action.

Ignoring some of the other awkwardness in the provided sentence, I would write it as "You might feel that it is impossible for resistance to be strictly equal to zero, because that could lead to a contradiction with Ohm's law." To be idiomatic, though, the next sentence would need to explain why it *is* possible for resistance to be equal to zero.